# jquery table wards ( right, left, up, down )

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table for which I need to use arrow keys move it.

**For example:**
when I press right arrow, function will be to find next right cell (input, select, textarea) in table and focus on it, and it will be same action for left up and down keys.

Is there any plugin for that? Or should I write code myself?

I hope you understand my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to fully understand, but still somehow here is the main idea for that.

**What tools or code to use:**

The jQuery will look at the `next()` sibling or whatever element on any keyEvent or clickEvent when you write the code for that.

**What was the key code:**

I will also tell you a very usefull web link, where you will be able to find the keycodes, believe me its the best link! http://whatthekeycode.com/ On this site, when you press any key, you will get the keyCode for that. And you will use that code for jQuery.

Suppose the keyPress is enter

```
if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {  
// do your work
}
```

**Note:** 13 is keyCode for enter, you can find others on the website I shared!

**jQuery to move around:**

I will teach you how to surf in the table, I will tell you about next only, use others for right left etc your self.

http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
$(this).next().focus();
```

`this` is used to do the job on the element on which the event occured. Then the `next()` and finally the FOCUS!

**What I would have done:**

I would have used my own ID for the element. As `id="rownumber_2` `id="rownumber_3` and on the `rownumber_2` an event would occur like this:

```
$(this).next().focus(); // where instead of this, it would be #rownumber_2
```

But do what makes you feel easy! :)

Comment: Thanks for answer ok its good for next and prev but what about up and down ?

Comment: Use the website to select each code for key down. And use the method that I have told you! Using ID surf the table. Don't use next() instead use the id and set focus to it. See the What I would have done section.